# One to many relationship for constant data

Tags: mysql, normalization

I am saving a book inside a database, so that it can be properly queried. The book I'm working with has constant data. Not a character of it will be changed in the future in any way, once the book has been loaded.

Now the book has many chapters and each chapter belongs to one book only. This is a one-to-many relationship.

The thing I want to ask:  Should I create another table for this relation or put the chapter serial and name in the same table?

This will cause redundancy. No doubt. But querying and reporting would be easy (I think, maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

In the table `Chapter` you should have a column `book_id`.

That is the standard way to implement many:1.  There no need for an extra table; that is only for many:many.